# Redirigir solo una vez

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Tengo un index.html que hace una redirección automática con la función window.location a otro dominio distinto. El problema es que si el usuario le da atrás al navegador vuelve a hacer la redirección, por lo que es un bucle.

Cómo puedo hacer que si un usuario le da atrás en el navegador no redirija de nuevo? por lo que sé únicamente se puede hacer guardando una cookie cada vez y hacer la redirección sólo si la cookie no existe, es así?

En este caso, cómo puedo hacer este proceso y cuál sería el código?

Con esta línea en el index.html sería suficiente para la parte de guardar una cookie para cada usuario?

document.cookie = "cookie1";

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Tu necesitas que solo la primera vez que ingresen al sitio le redireccione a la otra página.... estoy es un poco amplio... Puedes explicarte mejor..

Comment: Sí, exacto. Sólo necesito que haga la redirección la primera vez.

Answer (score 3):

Haz la redirección usando

```
window.location.replace("ejemplo.com");
```

Esto hará que la página que hace la redirección no quede guardada en el histórico del navegador regresando así la url previa.

Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer uso del LocalStorage para almacenar una variable, preguntar si ya existe la variable con algún indicador. algo como esto:

```
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    if(localStorage.getItem("a")){
    // Agregamos el item llamado a
    localStorage.setItem("a", "entro");
   }else{
    //Como si existe el item a, aquí haces tu redirecciòn
    //Agrega tu código de redirección
   }
} else {
    alert("No soporta LocalStorage");
}
```

Ojo: LocalStorage tiene tiempo de vida en el navegador, creo que debes pensar en eso también.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41416/discussion-on-answer-by-alfonso-carrasco-redirigir-solo-una-vez).

Comment: Muchas gracias Luggi Mendoza, aprendida la lección.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar eso como dice alfonso:

```
  if (typeof(wStorage) !== "undefined") {
      if(localStorage.getItem("a")){
      // Agregamos el item llamado a
       localStorage.setItem("a", "entro");
      }else{
       //Como si existe el item a, aquí haces tu redirecciòn
       //Agrega tu código de redirección
       }
      } else {
       alert("No soporta LocalStorage");
    },
```

pero no es necesario guardar variante..

Fuente: [Tecnologia Geek](https://www.tecnologiageek.com)